# Bypassing constructor in Python 2.7

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose I have the following chain of inheritance:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        print "BASE"
        print a
        print b

class Inherit1(Base):
    def __init__(self, a=3, b=4):
        print "INHERIT1"
        super(Inherit1, self).__init__(a=a, b=b)

class Inherit2(Inherit1):
    def __init__(self, a=5, b=6):
        print "INHERIT2"
        super(Inherit2, self).__init__(a=a, b=b)

Inherit2()
```

It would output:

```
INHERIT2
INHERIT1
BASE
5
6
```

But I would like to bypass the constructor of Inherit1, i.e. output

```
INHERIT2
BASE
5
6
```

is there a way of doing so?

**EDIT** I cannot change Base/Inherit1, I can only edit Inherit2.

Comment: The code you provide will not produce the output you provide.

Comment: It doesn't do what you claim.  One is obviously a typo, but the actual output is: `INHERIT2` `BASE` `5` `5`

Comment: Other questions:  Is there a reason you _need_ to inherit from (I assume) `Inherit1`?  Are you allowed to change `Inherit1` or `Base`?  There are many options, but which ones are _good_ depend in part on why you're doing this, and what your restrictions are.  This question is so abstract that it's hard to recommend one over another.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase No, I am not permitted to change the Inherit1 or Base code, they are from 3rd party.

Comment: Is it a requirement that `Inherit2` inherits from `Inherit1`?

Comment: @Hamms I just need to rewrite the constructor of Inherit1 because I need to pass additional parameter to Base. Yet I cannot monkey patch the original Inherit1 constructor.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Can `Inherit2` simply inherit from `Base`?

Comment: What kind of thing is `Inherit1` doing that you want to avoid?  Is it that _any_ instantiation has some ugly side effect (like that `print` command), or is it just that it doesn't take enough parameters?  (If the second case, then I don't think your example shows that at all.)  Your question focused entirely on the side effect, but your latest comment is all about parameter passing.

Comment: @Hamms No, because I need methods in Inherit1.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Right, in my case I just need to pass additional parameter to `Base`, which I did not show it at all, because I am wondering if there is any generic way of bypassing the parent constructor.

Comment: Do these classes actually call `super` as you've shown?  Usually, a chain of `super` calls makes heavy use of keyword arguments (with each class removing only the items they use), so you should be able to just add `base_only_key=value` to the `Inherit1` initializer call, and let it get passed onward to `Base.__init__`.   Again, _if_ the initializers were written to do that...  (See "[Python's `super()` Considered Super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)" by Raymond Hettinger, a Python core developer.)

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Unfortunately, the Inherit1 does not accept kwargs, and that is the reason why I ask this question. but it seems that Mr.Me has a reasonable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Ha we where all stumped when there is a very easy solution.

When calling super change `super(Inherit2, self)` to `super(Inherit1, self)` like so

```
class Inherit2(Inherit1):
    def __init__(self, a=5, b=5):
        print "INHERIT2"
        super(Inherit1, self).__init__(a=a, b=b)
```

Comment: It's fairly bad design for a parent class to have awareness of the implementation details of its child classes

Comment: I have changed my answer to a better one that does not have this problem :)

Comment: Just remove the `Base` from the inheritance and this is good.